# Why does chemistry markup (mhchem) fail on iOS app?

Tags: bug, status-completed

This is what chemical equations look like on the stack exchange iOS app:

[image: iOS screenshot]

The same content works fine in Safari on iOS.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: The biology and Chemistry sites need a different configuration for MathJax, it looks like the iOS app uses the default SE Mathjax configuration which doesn't support chemical formulas.

Comment: This is a question that belongs to [meta.se] (if there is not already an answer). Btw. it is the same in the android app.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233623/260760

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, there was a missing MathJax extension. This will be fixed in the next update to the iOS app in the Appstore.